# gnuGPG : decrypting an encrypted file does not require password

Tags: password, encryption, gnupg

I am new at gpg and I have just encrypted a file and decrypted it. I was asked to enter the passphrase for the first time.

Then, when I decrypt the file again gpg does not ask for any password anymore. This is not secure.

I would like to make it ask for my password everytime I try to dercypt the file.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you logout then log back in, does it require a password ?